# I need to create the table content PHP loop

Tags: php, loops

I want too create a php loop table with 10 row and 1 column. There should be a loop of every odd row should print "H" and even row need to have select menu of year. I'm beginner of php
I tried this :

```
<?php
function year() 
{
   echo '<select>';
   for ($i = 1998; $i<2015;)
   { 
       echo "<option>$i</option>";
       $i++;
   }
   echo '</select>'; 
} 

$try = year();
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($row =1; $row < 10;)
{
   echo "<tr><td>$row</td></tr>
   <tr><td>$try</td></tr>";
   $row++;
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Remove the ; after 2015 and $row

Comment: I think you should increment your variables in if(..) not inside the execution code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    function year()
    {
        $select = "";
        $select .= '<select>';
        for ($i = 1998; $i<2015;)
        { $select .= "<option>$i</option>";
        $i++;
        }
        return $select .= '</select>';
        }

        $try = year();
        echo '<table border="1">';
        for ($row =1; $row < 10;)
        {
        echo "<tr><td>$row</td><td>$try</td></tr>";
        $row++;
    }

    echo '</table>';
?>
```

```html
    <table border="1"><tr><td>1</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td><select><option>1998</option><option>1999</option><option>2000</option><option>2001</option><option>2002</option><option>2003</option><option>2004</option><option>2005</option><option>2006</option><option>2007</option><option>2008</option><option>2009</option><option>2010</option><option>2011</option><option>2012</option><option>2013</option><option>2014</option></select></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function year(){
    $select = "";
    $select .= '<select>';
    for ($i = 1998; $i<2015;){
        $select .= "<option>$i</option>";
        $i++;
    }
    return $select .= '</select>';
}

$try = year();
echo '<table border="1">';
    for ($row =1; $row < 11; $row++){
        if ($row % 2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr><td>$try</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr><td>H</td></tr>"; 
        }
    }
echo '</table>';
```

The output is:

[image]

Regards